# Removing null=True from Django model CharField are values updated to empty string

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a error being thrown when I navigate to my ListCreateAPIView base url:

```
url(r'^tests/$', TestList.as_view())
```

error:

```
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

which I believe to be related to the null=True in many of my CharField's throughout my various models. I ran into this error when attempting to add
[Django Rest Framework Parsers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#formparser) to a ListAPIView like so:

```
class TestList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    """

    queryset = Tests.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestSerializer
    filter_class = TestFilter
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser)

class Courses(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    test = models.ForeignKey('Tests',
                             blank=True,
                             null=True,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Tests(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

it's either getting upset because of the null=True on the CharField's or perhaps because of the test foreign key I'm not totally sure? Would removing null=True and migrating solve this issue? Additionally, I should probably remove the null=True on CharField's anyway, would that be updated retroactively in the database?

Comment: Hard to tell from only that info but I can tell you straight away — ListAPIView does not give you .post() method. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview

Comment: Is there anything additional I can provide to help clarify?

Comment: At which point do you get the error.

Comment: Sure (post updated) I get it when navigating to url(r'^tests/$', TestList.as_view())

Comment: So you get the error when you just going to the URL? Not posting or anything? Also why are you overloading post method with return none.

Comment: Yes exactly. I will need to override the post method, but first need to get the url to actually load. Removed it for clarity for the time being.

Comment: Your models are fine. Try doing the minimum setup: http://dpaste.com/1CR1HE5

Comment: yeah I did this the end point worked fine before I added the parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser) to the TestList

Comment: Does the same happen if you use just FormParser or just MultiPartParser?

Comment: As a general advice with Python question, please add the backtrace. This helps a lot others to figure out where the issue is and focus on that part.

Comment: And in your case, we'd need the serializer as well.